# How to add a label to all pull-request matching a query in Github

Tags: github, label, pull-request

We added a new flow in Github and I would like to mark all merged pull-requests prior to a date with a label.

Do you know if there are some tooling that would let me do that in batch?

One way of doing it is to paginate all PR 25 by 25 and add the label but with more than 500 pages I am asking myself if there is a better way.

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic, unfortunately. Did you have a look at the GitHub CLI? It does pagination for you, and something like `gh pr list -L 2000 -s all` shows 2000 PRs.

Comment: You are right, I'm closing it